# String.Format. Looking whether needed format exist

Tags: c#, string.format

I need a special string format for numbers. Maybe someone know such variant and can help me.

Algorithm:

1) if `number is < 0` (f.e. -1), then I need to have such `string: "-1"`.

2) if `number is >= 0` (f.e. 1), then I need to have such `string: " 1"`.

I don't need help like "make with if or ternary operator" - I know how to do that, but I'm interesting in existing format. Thank you.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you can just use `.ToString()`. This will give you "-1" for -1 and "1" for 1.

If you really need that extra space in there, then just pad a `string.Format` with your required spaces.

Comment: ...`ToString()` does it.. `int number = -1;  Console.WriteLine(number.ToString());`. Output is "-1"

Comment: @GEEF, i need a space only when >= 0. And don't need when number is <0

Comment: @GiladGreen, I need a space in case when number is >= 0 but i need it in one format

Comment: @ГошаПартитура - cool :) missed that.

Comment: @ГошаПартитура for future reference, that piece of information is critical to answering this question correctly. Try to include little details like that in the original question when possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format you are looking for is this one. Since zero is specific scenario, it is added explicitly.

```
string numberToString = number.ToString(" #;-#; 0");
```

Comment: Shoudln't that be `" #;-#; 0"`? (space before zero as well)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
String.Format("\"{0}\"", value);
```

I am not sure whether you are meaning anything else. It looks pretty simple

Comment: what is it?) It just outputs value with quotes. I need string "-1"  if number is -1 and string " 1" if number is 1